# Shouldn't an Images X and Y resolution match the DPI?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, winforms, bitmap

An image has a default resolution of 96, but the DPI varies from 72, 150 and 300+..  shouldn't they be the same for best result on the screen and printer?

I haven't ever in code, changed the resolution of any image.   The images I generate look proportionate to the way they look on the screen (WPF and/or WinForms), I am just wondering what the impact is of changing it.  Coordinates seem to stay the same.

Am I confusing Image resolution and Screen graphics pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DPI is a reference number, intended to get the image displayed at the intended physical size.  Proper software sets the DPI of the image to the dots-per-inch resolution of the device that created the image.

> the DPI varies from 72, 150 and 300+..

72 makes it likely that the artist created it with a painting program that ran on an Apple machine.  96 is the common number for a Windows machine.  150 says he used a nice monitor, increasingly more common today with hires monitors becoming a lot more affordable.  300 would only be common for a very cheap scanner or camera.  Practical scanners and cameras have a CCD that can do a much better job, 1200 and up are not unusual.

> images I generate look proportionate to the way they look on the screen

Very much intentional, DPI helps the rendering software to make the image look the same size.  Even though, say, a printer has a resolution that is *much* higher than the DPI of a monitor.  The printing software makes sure to rescale the image, making it ~6 times bigger.  Without that correction, the image would turn into a post-stamp on paper.

> I am just wondering what the impact is of changing it

You'd just force the rendering software to resize the image.  They still have the same physical size on the monitor and on paper.

> shouldn't they be the same for best result

The ideal is to have the DPI of the device that created the image the same as the device that displays it.  No interpolation is necessary, so it is the fastest way to display it.  And every pixel in the source image is a 1-to-1 match with the pixel on the display device so it is very sharp with no artifacts.  It is just not a very practical ideal since you can't always control what devices where used.  Never practical when it was a scanner or camera.  Could be practical if it was made with a painting program since you might favor the sharpness of the displayed image.  That's however rapidly fading as an option as well with hires monitors becoming more common, dealing with unpredictable window content size is pretty difficult.